# No symbols have been loaded for this document - and apparently not executed either?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS2015 C++ solution which relies on code that's at global scope in the .cpp being run, because it does some registration that makes the factory system work.  Slightly more specifically:

- the Utility project is a static library which contains the factory system
- the CompositeValue project is a static library which contains the objects that need to register themselves
- the CompositeValueTest project is an executable that runs my unit tests
- CompositeValueTest references CompositeValue, which references Utility
- There are several other pairs of libraries which use the same pattern as CompositeValue and CompositeValueTest, all of which work.

For whatever reason most (but not all) of the .cpp files in CompositeValue are not being initialized when I start up CompositeValueTest - as best I can tell, none of the global scope code in the .cpp files is being run at all.

Interestingly, if I explicitly #include the .cpp file (but not the .h file), the problem goes away for that file (but not for any of the others).  That seems like a really dirty way to solve the problem, though.

Another symptom is that when I place a breakpoint in the troublesome .cpp files, I get the infamous "no symbols have been loaded for this project" message.

I read all the threads I can find on that error.  I tried reloading.  Optimization is disabled (though I would hope that when I enable it, my code will still be initialized properly!!).  When I check the Modules window, I don't see the CompositeValues project listed at all, but CompositeValueTests is there, and looks correct.  I checked all the settings match those of projects that are working, and then when that didn't solve it I got rid of my .vcxproj files, copied ones that work, and used those.

It doesn't seem like my problem is really that the symbols aren't being loaded, but rather that the file isn't being included at all - but when I check the build output, it does report that it's getting built (and the build fails if I introduce errors).

Comment: If the executable doesn't explicitly reference anything in a particular obj file, the linker is going to discard that whole file, global initializers and all. For that reason, magical build-time self-registration schemes are difficult to get to work.

Comment: Make CompositeValue a `dll` instead of a static library and the self registering should work.